# understanding closures in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, ios8

So I am having trouble with closures with in my swift app, in which I am trying to use parse as a BaaS.  Particularly I do not understand why I cannot assign a variable within a closure and have access to it outside of it. my code that does work looks like:

```
class SecondView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var label:UILabel!

var budgetInfo:NSArray = []

var item:PFObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Budget")
    query.whereKey("creditor", equalTo: "rent")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (object:PFObject!, error:NSError!)  in

        self.label.text = NSString(format: "%@", object.objectForKey(key: "amount") as NSNumber)

    })

}
```

this code works perfectly how ever when I try to  assign `var item:PFObject!` with in the block like this:

```
class SecondView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var label:UILabel!

var budgetInfo:NSArray = []

var item:PFObject!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Budget")
    query.whereKey("creditor", equalTo: "rent")
    query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (object:PFObject!, error:NSError!)  in

        self.item = object

    })

    label.text = NSString(format: "%@", item.objectForKey("amount") as NSNumber)
}
```

i get an exception that states

```
unexpectedly found nil when unwrapping optional
```

So obviously the item variable does not get assigned with in the closure, so does that mean I should assign all of my values inside the closure or am I leaving something out?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets assigned, it just happens before the closure finishes execution. That's why

```
 item.objectForKey("amount")
```

"item" is nil

The solution is - putting whatever logic you have there inside the closure, which is asynchronous i believe.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. I was thinking that was the case but my inexperience left me uncertain.  Just trying to write the cleanest and most sensible code I can.